# Avoiding the PerformanceCounter.NextValue's InvalidOperationException exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, performancecounter

```
var counter = new PerformanceCounter{};
counter.CategoryName = "Process";
counter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
counter.InstanceName = someProcessName;

if ( PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists( someProcessName, "Process" ) )
{
    // For any reason the process terminates EXACTLY at this point
    counter.NextValue();
    // we'll get a InvalidOperationException exception here
}
```

Is there any possibility to use PerformanceCounter.NextValue method in a safe manner. Just for the record, I know It's very unlikely to have this type of scenario.

Comment: There is an implicit race here, you can't be sure you'll get the Process.Exited event before the counter becomes invalid.  Nothing a try/catch couldn't handle.

Answer (score 0):

Look at MSDN - InvalidOperationException is throwed when `The instance is not correctly associated with a performance counter`.

[PerformanceCounter.NextValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter.nextvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try to initialize your counter with `RawValue` property:

```
// Initialize the counter.
counter.RawValue = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
```

If this won't help - check if category and counter names are valid

Comment: Correct. But the question is about how to deal with the situation when you check the instance, and if true you try to use NextValue, BUT if in between these 2 steps your instance is broked / deleted / name it, you'll get an exception.

Answer (score 0):

use try-catch like this:

```
var counter = new PerformanceCounter{};
counter.CategoryName = "Process";
counter.CounterName = "% Processor Time";
counter.InstanceName = someProcessName;
try
{
   if ( PerformanceCounterCategory.InstanceExists( someProcessName, "Process" ) )
   {
       // For any reason the process terminates EXACTLY at this point
       counter.NextValue();
   }
}
catch(InvalidOperationException error)
{
   //deal with exception
}
```

Comment: whenever you expect an exception to occur at some point use this statement, if you don't know what type of exceptions will occur just write catch(Exception error) and do what you want to do(usually printing stack trace)